# Powershell and exchange in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have the following code in C# that I use to connect to exchange through powershell.

The following code works fine, however there is one more command that I need in order to use the exchange cmdlets.

Here is the code I have now.

```
Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();

PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri("https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/"));
command.AddParameter("Credential", creds);
command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Basic");
command.AddParameter("AllowRedirection");

powershell.Commands = command;

try
{
    runspace.Open();
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;

    Collection<PSObject> commandResults = powershell.Invoke();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (PSObject ps in commandResults)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(ps.ToString());
    }

    sb.AppendLine();

    lbl.Text += sb.ToString();
}
finally
{
    // dispose the runspace and enable garbage collection
    runspace.Dispose();
    runspace = null;
    // Finally dispose the powershell and set all variables to null to free
    // up any resources.
    powershell.Dispose();
    powershell = null;
}
```

My problem is that I still need to run the command `import-pssession $session` where `$session` is the output of my first command. However I am not sure how I can declare that output as the variable $session or something like:

```
 PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
 command.AddCommand("Import-PSSession");
 command.AddParameter("Session", #Not sure how to put session info which is what the first command produces into here.);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using creating a Remote Runspace instead, an example is given below. You can reference the following article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706560(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
string schemaURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";
Uri connectTo = new Uri("https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/");
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(user,secureStringPassword ); // the password must be of type SecureString
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(connectTo,schemaURI, credential);
connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 5;
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

try
{
    Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
    remoteRunspace.Open();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Handle error 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the section "Remote Request using a local run space (Scripting the remote class)" in the following technet blog
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/11/02/3408653.aspx

I believe what you are trying to achieve is:

```
    // Set the runspace as a local variable on the runspace
    powershell = PowerShell.Create();
    command = new PSCommand();
    command.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
    command.AddParameter("Name", "ra");
    command.AddParameter("Value", result[0]);
    powershell.Commands = command;
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
    powershell.Invoke();
```

Where  result[0] is the result of the first remote session created. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Then you can import the session in order to use it:
        Using powershell__2 As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
        command.AddScript("Import-PSSession -Session $ra")
        powershell__2.Commands = command
        powershell__2.Runspace = runspace
        powershell__2.Invoke()
        End Using